# mysqldump unknown option no beep

Tags: mysql, windows

I'm running MySQL 5.5 on Windows, attempting a mysqldump:

```
 "C:\WebServer\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump.exe" -u user -ppassword database > "C:\backup.sql"
```

But get error:

> mysqldump: unknown option '--no beep'

This is a pretty basic command, and works on two other development boxes, so not sure what is causing this?

Comment: solved: disabled 'no-beep' in my.ini

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26461338/17389 is a better solution (putting it in the correct place instead of removing it) if there was a reason for having no-beep in the first place

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Same issue, commented out (#) the no-beep line in the MySQL my.ini, solved the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Something in an environment variable or my.cnf file?

For what it's worth, when I put the no-beep option (a valid option for the mysql client, but not for mysqldump) in the `[client]` section of my config file, I get

```
mysqldump: unknown option '--no-beep'
```

(As mentioned in [naitsirch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26461338/17389), it should be moved from the `[client]` section to the `[mysql]` section so it doesn't try to use it for other client programs such as mysqldump.)

Answer (score 10):

I found [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30667/unknown-option-no-beep) on dba.stackexchange.com, which is very helpful:

> The `no-beep` [option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_no-beep) causes the `mysql` command line client not to beep when errors occur.
>
> If that's an option you want, it should be in the `[mysql]` section of your `my.cnf` [or my.ini]. This error suggests that it's in the `[client]` section of your `my.cnf`, which causes [...] to throw the error since the option isn't recognized.
>
> Check your `my.cnf` and either remove the line or place it in the `[mysql]` section instead of `[client]` and you should be good.
>
> > The [client] option group is read by all client programs (but not by mysqld). This enables you to specify options that apply to all clients. For example, [client] is the perfect group to use to specify the password that you use to connect to the server. (But make sure that the option file is readable and writable only by yourself, so that other people cannot find out your password.) Be sure not to put an option in the [client] group unless it is recognized by all client programs that you use. Programs that do not understand the option quit after displaying an error message if you try to run them.
>
> -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html

Answer (score 1):

One note relating to this, you have to be aware of your various installed MySQL products.  The following scenario best explains it.

- C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini (created from a previous installation)
- C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini (someone copied this here, who knows why)
- C:\Program Files\MySQL\my.ini (created by MySQL Installer Config Wizard)

So you might assume that the MySQL Workbench draws settings from the `my.ini` file inside of the MySQL version you're working against. This would be a safe assumption as part of setting up a configuration for administration in the Workbench requires pointing to the `my.ini` specific to that installation. However that is incorrect as I've found it latches onto the one located at `C:\Program Files\MySQL\my.ini` as the one to use.  You thus have to edit this file to get the Workbench to function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Despite removing the -no--beep otion from the client section in the my.ini file specified in the properties of the mysql service, the problem persisted. The MYSQL56 service set up was using my.in from E:\Program Data\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\ . And this ini file had no -no--beep option under the [client] section.

So what was the problem?

In my setup, mysqldump.exe is residing at C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin. When running this as a command line option, mysql was using C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini. This ini file contained the no--beep option in it. mysqldump was not using the my.ini specified by the service but rather the one directory up.

Deleting C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution is to use `--no-defaults` option

Eg : `mysqldump --no-defaults -u root -p [DB_NAME] > [FILE_NAME].sql`

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the no-beep option worked for me, but I had to change the **my.ini file in my windows directory**! 
I'm using windows 10 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

solved it for me too

C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0

reboot pc

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very easy
If you are also facing the same ---no beep--- problem

Then simply press the windows button and search for mysql installer community
over there you will find an option of reconfigure on the link of mysql server

Just click on it and follow the few steps and after that test if its done by opening the command promp and type mysql -u root -p

and type the root password

I hope this would also be helpful for you guys as I found it bymyself trying to solve

This problem was generated because there was no connection established between mysql databases so we just initiated a connection and thus made it run as usual

Answer (score -5):

Removing `my.ini` from `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6` solved it for me.