# MySQL Dump unknown option '-no-beep'

Tags: mysql

On the old server I used the **mysqldump** command to make me a backup of the MySQL database.

On the new server, with version 5.6 of MySQL, the same command gives me the error

```
unknown option '-no-beep'
```

whatever it insert.

I also searched on the internet but I could not find any help....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210769/mysqldump-unknown-option-no-beep

Comment: If you searched [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+"-no-beep") it's the first result ;)

Comment: Commented out (#) the no-beep line in the MySQL my.ini, solved the problem, thank you for help.

Comment: Im sorry but in this case how to set answered the question?

Comment: I added it as more of an answer below:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your init file for mysql (my.ini), comment out the `no-beep` line, as it is no longer a valid option in mysql > 5.0.

See answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210769/mysqldump-unknown-option-no-beep)