# the solution for mysqldump unknown option no beep, didn't works

Tags: mysql

hello i have the problem with mysqldump: unknown option '--no beep'
I read these topics [mysqldump unknown option no beep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210769/mysqldump-unknown-option-no-beep) and [MySQL Dump unknown option '-no-beep'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083831/mysql-dump-unknown-option-no-beep)
both links says that i must to comment the line "#no-beep" I did it and I still have the same problem, also I deleted the my.ini file and nothing

this is my my.ini :

```
# honor these values, you need to specify it as an option during the
# MySQL client library initialization.
# [client]
#no-beep

# pipe
# socket=mysql port=3306

[mysql]

default-character-set=utf8


# SERVER SECTION
# ------------------
```

I am in 5.6 MySQL version

this is the command that I'm trying: mysqldump -u user -p pass -all-databases > C:\recover.sql But I don't know if using Data Export from MySQL workbench  is the same command but both ways didn't works

Comment: what's the command you're using?

Comment: Please give a better description, and if you have more config file to show, show it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30667/unknown-option-no-beep

Comment: this is the command that I'm trying: mysqldump -u user -p pass -all-databases > C:\recover.sql But I don't know if using Data Export from MySQL workbench is the same command but both ways didn't works

Comment: please i realy need an answer

Answer (score 1):

Move that `no-beep` option to `[mysql]` section rather

```
[mysql]
no-beep
default-character-set=utf8
```