# how to back uop all databases at once using mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I am trying to back up all  databases at once from mysql server but i am getting the following error:

```
mysqldump: unknown option '--no-beep'
```

the command i am running is the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump" --uXXXXX --pXXXXXX --all-databases > c:\MySQL_DB_Backups\%mydate%_all_databases.sql
```

Any help is appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: Try a single dash in front `u` and `p`. `-uXXXXX -pXXXXX`.

Comment: that didn't work.:( Any other idea?

Comment: if you post your [own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) means you can able accept the answer after 48 hours. It will help others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysqldump unknown option no beep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210769/mysqldump-unknown-option-no-beep)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by commenting the line in my.cnf where it says "no beep"

```
[Client]
#no Beep
```