# What's wrong with mysqldump?

Tags: mysql

What's wrong with mysqldump -you type command "C:\MySQL>mysqldump --help" 
It's displayed:

mysqldump: unknown option '--no-beep'

No matter you type with mysqldump, it always responses:

C:\MySQL>mysqldump
mysqldump: unknown option '--no-beep'

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysqldump unknown option no beep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210769/mysqldump-unknown-option-no-beep)

Answer (score 0):

--no-beep is an option for the mysql command-line query tool, not for mysqldump.

I would guess that you have entered the no-beep in your my.cnf configuration file under the [client] section, which applies to both mysql and mysqldump clients. You need to move no-beep to the [mysql] section of the config file, so it applies only to the mysql client.

Comment: No  --no-beep is used with the mysqldump command. Even you type mysqldump without any others, it gives you the error.

Answer (score 0):

Before mysqldump ran well, but after MySQL was upgraded, this tool does not work. Where is the problem? No matter you type in the command with mysqldump, it always responses "mysqldump: unknown option '--no-beep'"

Answer (score 0):

Commented out (#) the no-beep line in the MySQL my.ini, solved the problem.
See: [mysqldump unknown option no beep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210769/mysqldump-unknown-option-no-beep)