# mysqldump windows unknown option '--no beep'

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem with the mysqldump command in general (import/export).
I write in windows command window the following:

```
C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin> mysqldump -u root -p nameofdabase> C:\temp\dumpfile.sql
```

and i get "mysqldump unknown option --no beep". It doesn't ask me for my password and it doesn't seem to recognize the mysqldump command even though I see it in the bin directory.   What am I doing wrong??I have tried everything from changing paths to changing backslashes. Anything I have found online that seems to work keeps giving me the same kind of error.
Any clues will be much appreciated...Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a line in my my.ini (or my.cnf) file that says "no-beep". This is an option for the mysql client, but not for mysqldump.

If you want the "no-beep" option for the mysql client only, edit your my.ini file and move it under the file section heading `[mysql]`.

See also [mysqldump unknown option no beep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210769/mysqldump-unknown-option-no-beep)

Answer (score 0):

There is a "default" `my.ini` here: `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini`.

It contains the `no-beep` option.

The MySQL Installer has my.ini templates for various versions in `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\Manifest\Templates\`, for some reason, all of it contains this option.